# (Win7:VC7): TaskMgr suggests "Memory Leak" as Two-Dimensional Static Arrays are Filled, Despite Initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, mfc

I have an MFC application compiled under VS VC7. I have a persistent and worrisome "memory leak" per Task Manager.

I downloaded a professional memory leak detection application, which highlighted some one-off calls to "new" in the VC7 core libraries related to sockets. So, I commented out all of the (one-time) calls from the main program to connect via the sockets. But, the leak persists.

Continuing to comment out whole sections of code, I seem to have isolated the main culprit, and I am very confused.

If I comment out the call to the following function (circular buffer, crude spin lock, called every second in a timer loop), taskmgr suggests there are essentially no more leaks:

```
void CIBTraderDlg::PushPriceVolume()
{
    INT i;

    InterlockedIncrement(&g_nNowRow); 

    if ( g_nNowRow == MAX_HISTORY) InterlockedExchange(&g_nNowRow, 0);

    for ( i = 0; i < g_Config.m_nFutureCount + g_Config.m_nSpreadCount; i++ )
    {
        pPH[i][g_nNowRow] = g_Config.m_pFutureInfos[i].dBid;
        pVH[i][g_nNowRow] = g_Config.m_pFutureInfos[i].nThisV;
    }

    if ( nHistoryCount < MAX_HISTORY ) InterlockedIncrement(&nHistoryCount);
}
```

The two arrays pPH and pVH are initialized as follows, global at the top:

```
DOUBLE pPH[MAX_CONTRACTS][MAX_HISTORY] = {0.00};
INT pVH[MAX_CONTRACTS][MAX_HISTORY] = {0};
```

both MAX_CONTRACTS and MAX_HISTORY known.

These are big arrays, as it happens. MAX_HISTORY = 86400 (seconds in a day)

(nb: I've done a lot of math and the arrays are being filled with the correct values)

Based on taskmgr, as the array is filled up with actual data the size of the program in memory grows, and dramatically (10K bytes/minute, for an application that is to run 7 x 24). But the array was defined static and of fixed size, and was to be prepopulated with zeroes. My thought had been, I have plenty of RAM and by doing it the way I did the size of the array in memory was fixed. Obviously, I was wrong. I've spent the last 2 days reading thru many articles on "better" and more elegant and efficient ways to allocate for multidimensional arrays, but I haven't read anywhere that what I did would not work.

Comment: Your `for` loop is dangerous since you don't throttle `i` to less than MAX_CONTRACTS.  In addition, you don't check if `g_nNowRow` is within bounds.

Comment: How do you identity memory leak by Windows Task manager?

Comment: Matt, under "processes" the "Memory (Private Working Set}" continues to grow seemingly ad infinitum. It alerted me to do more formal Memory Leak detection, since I had no "new"s in my own code and thus no obvious sources of leaks.

Comment: Paul, thanks,. I will clean that up.

Comment: @cjv - Once you add the additional condition to the loop, retest your code and see if there is any change.  Strange things can happen *if* you were going out of bounds.

Comment: @cjv: The Windows task manager isn't a reliable way to find leaks. If you're running in debug mode, you will see much higher than expected memory usage. In general, because of the way memory allocation works on Windows, you also don't have the guarantee that deleting 20 MB worth of objects will reduce memory usage by 20 MB (or at all).